# Especificando um EJB-client com o Maven

Tags: java, maven, ejb

Não estou conseguindo utilizar as interfaces de um EJB-client gerado pelo Maven.

Tenho basicamente 2 projetos separados e com funções distintas.
Um EAR que contém EJB's e um WAR que utiliza interfaces dos EJB's do pacote EAR.

Segue estrutura:

1. EAR

   1.2 - EJB
2. WAR (com a dependência do EJB-client).

Quando compilo o WAR ele vem com todas as classes do módulo EJB e não somente com as interfaces necessárias para a sua utilização.

Segue pom.xml do projeto WAR:

```war
<dependency>
  <groupId>br.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependencia-ejb</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>ejb-client</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra quem está enfrentando o mesmo problema, segue a solução:

Se todos os seus projetos (tanto o EAR que contém os EJB's quanto o WAR que utiliza as interfaces cliente dos EJB's) estão no mesmo workspace, você deve fechar o projeto EJB antes de gerar o WAR com as interfaces do EJB-CLIENT, caso contrário, o projeto WAR será compilado com todas as classes do EJB e não somente com as interfaces cliente necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro sua pergunta, mas pelo que entendi você está com problemas para sua  interface do módulo EJB no WAR... nesse caso altere o pom.xml do seu módulo WAR para o seguinte:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>br.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependencia-ejb</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Verifique também se seu projeto EAR está com ambas as dependências declaradas no pom.xml
E também, neste caso, você deve empacotar e rodar seu projeto como EAR não como WAR.